Blazor webApp deja de funcionar al refrescar una pagina con SignalR
Estoy desarrollando una webapp donde diferentes componentes se comunican mediante signalR.
Acabo de publicar la aplicación en IIS en Windows 11, configuré el protocolo de comunicación por web sockets y me pasa un problema que no está mientras corro la aplicación en Visual Studio:
Cuando varios equipos se conectan en el mismo o en diferentes componentes (páginas), normalmente al tercero, o cuando en un componente refresco la pagina 2 o 3 veces, la página se queda cargando y ya no funciona toda la webapp, no solo el componente del usuario que refresco.
Por lo general los componentes se unen a un grupo de la siguiente manera:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await cargar();

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/Hub"))
            .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[]
                {
                    TimeSpan.Zero,               // Primer intento inmediatamente
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),     // Segundo intento después de 2 segundos
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),     // Tercer intento después de 5 segundos
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)     // Intentos posteriores cada 10 segundos
                })
            .Build();

        hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        hubConnection.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);


        hubConnection.Reconnected += async (connectionId) =>
        {
            await UnirseAlProceso();
        };

        hubConnection.On<int, int>("ActualizarProgreso", (ordenId, cantidad_Nueva) =>
        {
            var orden = ordenes.Find(x => x.Id == ordenId);
            if (orden != null)
            {
                orden.Cantidad_producida = cantidad_Nueva;
                InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                if (orden.Avance() == 100)
                {
                    ordenes.Remove(orden);
                }
            }
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        await UnirseAlProceso();

        cargando = false;
    }

Al debuggear remotamente en el servidor, veo que el proceso se queda en await hubConnection.StartAsync();. no da errores realmente, ni genera errores en log, visor de eventos o en los propios logs del IIS.
Supuse que podría estar creando múltiples conexiones por lo que agregue antes:
if (hubConnection != null && hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
{
    await hubConnection.StopAsync();
    await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
}

Sin embargo el problema continua exactamente igual. Lo mismo si cambio a el método OnAfterRenderAsync.
¿Alguien sabe cómo resolver este problema?
